# How would SQL table store Map Legends?

Tags: sql, legend

I am not asking which Map legend classification to choose. But assume I have picked one, how would I store it properly in the SQL tables? The reason of asking is, in the end, I need to store more info than I expected... Hope someone could verify.

Consider 3 cases below:

1. **Numeric, Range**

[image]

2. **Numeric, Single Value**

[image]

3. **Alphabet, Single Value**

[image]

To be able to store it properly, SO THAT I am able to do logic classification at real time (do coloring), meaning, I need to store the operators as well (less than [`lt`], greater than [`gt`], equal [`eq`], etc)

Ends up, Say I have 2 tables:

**LegendSetup**

Column:

```
1. LegendKey (int)
2. Type (varchar)
3. Min (decimal)
4. Max (decimal)
```

**LegendValueSetup**

Column:

```
1. ValueKey (int) //AutoIncrement PK
2. LegendKey (int) //FK
3. RangeNumeric (decimal) //numeric
4. RangeAlpha (varchar) //alphabet
5. RangeOperator (varchar) //eq, lt, gt
6. RangeShow (varchar) //for display purpose
7. HexColor (varchar)
```

Is that how it normally works?

Comment: What do you mean by "do coloring"? Given a x,y-coordinate on the map (or rather its value), assign it the HexColor according to your LegendValueSetup?

Comment: The map loads geojson. Inside the geojson, it defines the polygon with attributes (eg: Polygon 1 has a population = 150). So, ya, that polygon would be filled with the HexColor according to the LegendValueSetup, after doing the logic comparison.

Comment: `LegendSetup` table with only one column? That is probably a mistake or an example that I do not comprehend properly.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal oops. I added back some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you only need ranges and equalities I suggest you don't use explicit operators, but ranges like this:

```
CREATE TABLE LegendValueSetup (
  ValueAlpha varchar,
  ValueNumeric decimal,
  LowerNumeric decimal,
  UpperNumeric decimal,
  ... -- other columns
)
```

For your examples 2 and 3 you would just store the explicit values in the `ValueAlpha` and `ValueNumeric` column.
For example 1 you would have to think about if `LowerNumeric` is an inclusive and `UpperNumeric` an exclusive bound and vice versa. Then you can store the legend like this:

```
LowerNumeric | UpperNumeric | Color
NULL         |   100        |  Black
100          |   200        |  Red
200          |   400        |  Orange
400          |   600        |  Yellow
600          |   NULL       |  Green
```

If you have now a value and want to get the color, you only have to query

```
SELECT color FROM LegendValueSetup WHERE LowerNumeric <= $value AND UpperNumeric > $value
```

You can of course go further and split the table into three different ones, one for each legend type.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Will come back again after verifying this.Thank you

Comment: I would add an attribute with `LegendValueType` so that it is allways clear, what type of object is stored in the db record.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I see your points. I would add that as well. You have my thanks.